# <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, href

What is the purpose of the following script in head?

```
<head>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
...
</head>
```

I somewhat understood that base href is used to set the initial portion of default path. So where does this set the url to?
Later on I'm using

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <p>Click one of the following choices.</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/tab1')}"><a href="#/tab1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/tab2')}"><a href="#/tab2">tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <pre>{{ path }}</pre>
</body>
```

with the following controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isActive = function(route) {
        $scope.path = $location.path();
        return $location.path() === route;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<base>` element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within the document.

From the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.location) definition:

> The Document.location read-only property returns a Location object,
>   which contains information about the URL of the document and provides
>   methods for changing that URL and load another URL.

In your case it sets the `base href` to the current URL.  Additionally, `document.location` is equivalent to `document.location.href`.

Comment: Hey, could you help me with why is it needed? Isn't the current URL default? To test routing tabs, I downloaded this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fuVb0mzhmDCKr1xKp7Rn). I downloaded as a zip and ran it as it is, but its not working, but its running on the fiddle. Something to do with the location url?

Comment: The base URL is used by all relative URLs within the document.  Can you link your fiddle?